# What does eventual or strong mean in the context of Google Cloud Storage consistency?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

What does eventual or strong mean in the context of Google Cloud Storage consistency?

Comment: While i dig that you add this question as a form of documentation i don't see how it's programming related and therefore it is more suited for http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform

Answer (score 2):

From the [Consistency](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques?hl=en#consistency) section of the documentation:

> Google Cloud Storage provides strong global consistency for all
>   read-after-write, read-after-update, and read-after-delete operations,
>   including both data and metadata. When you upload a file (PUT) to
>   Google Cloud Storage, and you receive a success response, the object
>   is immediately available for download (GET) and metadata (HEAD)
>   operations, from any location in Google's global network.

That means it will take time to replicate all over the networks and it will not be available until the replication is finished (to demonstrate strong consistency). It is more understandable by the statement from the doc that says, "When you upload an object, the object is not available until it is completely uploaded." And that is why, the latency for writing to a globally-consistent replicated store may be slightly higher than to a non-replicated or non-committed store because a success response is returned only when multiple writes complete, not just one. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques?hl=en#consistency) what it says more.